# python getting date from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset with non-static date structure

Such as

```
Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:13:12 +0000 (UTC)
Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:32:59 +0100
Tue, 05 Dec 2017 11:03:34 GMT
08 Dec 2016 12:00:24
```

How to get the day, (hour+offset) and minute from a string like that without manual code using regex.

Comment: What is your desired output format? and how do you differentiate b/w manual code and regex?

Comment: i just wanna extract and change to categorical (for ml) @user5173426

Comment: Check [strptime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime). In your case you would probably need to implement additional fallback strategy to switch between different format types (e.g. `for format in formats` + `strptime` in `try ... except`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `timestring`:

```
import timestring

dt_1 = "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:13:12 +0000 (UTC)"
dt_2 = "Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:32:59 +0100"
dt_3 = "Tue, 05 Dec 2017 11:03:34 GMT"
dt_4 = "08 Dec 2016 12:00:24"

print(timestring.Date(dt_1))
print(timestring.Date(dt_2))
print(timestring.Date(dt_3))
print(timestring.Date(dt_4))
```

**EDIT:**

While I was at it, here is another cooler method:

Using [`dparser`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

dt_1 = "Fri, 13 Apr 2018 13:13:12 +0000 (UTC)"
dt_2 = "Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:32:59 +0100"
dt_3 = "Tue, 05 Dec 2017 11:03:34 GMT"
dt_4 = "08 Dec 2016 12:00:24"


print(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True))
print(dparser.parse(dt_2,fuzzy=True))
print(dparser.parse(dt_3,fuzzy=True))
print(dparser.parse(dt_4,fuzzy=True))
```

OUTPUT:

```
2018-04-13 13:13:12+00:00
2018-03-26 06:32:59+01:00
2017-12-05 11:03:34+00:00
2016-12-08 12:00:24
```

**EDIT 2:**

Why is `dparser` cooler?

> Invalid dates raise a ValueError:

```
invalid_dt = "Fri, 35 Apr 2018 13:13:12 +0000 (UTC)"
print(dparser.parse(invalid_dt,fuzzy=True))
```

OUTPUT:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

**EDIT 3:**

To get the `day`, `month`, `year`, `hour`, `minute` or `second`:

```
print(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).day)     # 13
print(dparser.parse(dt_2,fuzzy=True).month)   # 3
print(dparser.parse(dt_3,fuzzy=True).year)    # 2017
print(dparser.parse(dt_4,fuzzy=True).hour)    # 12
print(dparser.parse(dt_4,fuzzy=True).minute)  # 0
print(dparser.parse(dt_4,fuzzy=True).second)  # 24
```

**EDIT 4:**

If you want to get the name of the Day:

```
print(datetime.date(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True)).strftime("%a"))  # Fri
```

Comment: It seems that the output are not the good ones. For example: Fri 13 Apr gives 2019-02-15.

Comment: thanks for the help, that return a good string. any idea about the `day` ?

Comment: @BaltschunAli Ofcourse, just use the `day` attribute. like > 
`print(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).day)` returns `13`

Comment: sorry, i mean like `mon` , `fri` etc

Comment: Sure, you can use `print(datetime.date(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True)).strftime("%A"))` returns `Friday` or use `%a` if you want `Fri`

Comment: last problem, really thanks for your time.
an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)

Comment: Simply Convert that to an int i.e. int(x)

Comment: i found  a simple one `dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).weekday()`
thanks for helping. really thanks