# remove date from datetime field python sql

Tags: python, mysql, selenium

I have a field in SQL info1[11] it contain the:

```
DateTime format like this: 2019-01-31 17:30:00
```

so I wanted to date and time separate so I strip the time like that:

```
ticket_start_date = str(info1[11])[:10]
output : 2019-01-31
```

but for the time i am doing this but no luck:

```
 ticket_start_time = str(info1[11][11:])
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

Is there any other way to get the time only in this format.
The convention to write time is 'hh:mm:ss AM/PM' or 'hh:mm:ss'

I am selenium and SQL with python to automate some task

Comment: I think there is an error in the statement 'ticket_start_time = str(info1[11][11:])' change to 'ticket_start_time = str(info1[11])[11:]'

Comment: no need to do a manual slice, seek `strptime` and `strftime` for "loading string to datatime" or "dump datetime into string", there are good samples at official document, at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: yeah I didn't see the error. strptime and strftime will be a good approach

Comment: i got another error:    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a missing `(` in your current approach, should have been:

```
ticket_start_time = str(info1[11])[11:])
```

But I wouldn't encourage your current approach of `slicing` when there are already cooler, shorter and faster ways out there:

Using [`dparser`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782989/python-getting-date-from-string/54783126#54783126):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dt_1 = "2019-01-31 17:30:00"
print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).date()))
print("Time: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).time()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 2019-01-31
Time: 17:30:00
```

**EDIT**:

From the comments below this answer:

```
import datetime as dt
start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @Nandan you may use `.strftime('%p')`

Comment: i am already import datetime but i am getting this error AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') from this